# How can you customize or style a list/library's column headers in SharePoint Online Modern sites?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, spfx, sharepointframework, microsoft365

I am trying to Customize/Style the Column headers in SPO but can't able to do it modern UI. I Don't want do DOM Manipulation(since the classes can be changed at any time) but wanted to see if there's an alternative way where I can customize and introduce fluent UI icons into the column headers. Any help is appreciated.

[Column Header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVd1L.png)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, this is currently not possible. The closest thing that comes to this would be [custom view formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting). Here you can actually modify the OOTB header... but only hide it! Views allow you to [build your own header](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/custom-header-format), but this would not be able to leverage the custom logic currently in place (drop-down to sort/filter/etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you can use SPFX to inject CSS/js file to customize the list header.
[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss)